# How can I safely read string vals from SQL Server that may be null?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, isnull

When the Address2 column is empty, this line:

```
string address2 = sqlD8aReader.GetString(ADDRESS2_OFFSET);
```

...fails with:

```
  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232015
  Message=Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
       at HandheldServer.Models.SQLServerPOCRepository..ctor() in c:\HandheldServer\HandheldServer\Models\SQLServerPOCRepository.cs:line 58
  InnerException:
```

How can I safely read strings that might be null? Should it be dealt with in SQL somehow (if so, how?) or should it be dealt with in the reading/C# code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how your data is being populated, but often times when we execute a query where I work, if it's imperative to have empty strings instead of null for certain operations, we'll use `ISNULL(column, '')` on columns that might possibly return null so our application layer won't need to worry about whether or not the value is null, it will just handle it like a string.

Otherwise, if you want to handle it application side you can use this:

```
if(!sqlD8aReader.IsDBNull(ADDRESS2_OFFSET))
{
    string address2 = sqlD8aReader.GetString(ADDRESS2_OFFSET);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick one-liner would be

```
string address2 = sqlD8aReader.IsDBNull(ADDRESS2_OFFSET) 
                  ? null 
                  :sqlD8aReader.GetString(ADDRESS2_OFFSET);
```

or as an extension method:

```
public static GetStringOrNull(this IDataRecord dr, int i)
{
    return dr.IsDBNull(i) 
           ? null 
           : dr.GetString(i);
}
```

and call

```
string address2 = sqlD8aReader.GetStringOrNull(ADDRESS2_OFFSET);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in your sql query like:

```
    select * from SomeTable where SomeColumn is not null
```

This way you wouldn't get that exception. But you should also check if the returned value is null or not like akousmata said.

Comment: Caution: this will work in a dev scenario but it *might* not scale well in a busy OLTP SQL Server db that has millions of rows and SomeColumn isn't indexed. I would only use this if I could look at the execution plan  when run against a copy of a large prod database and verify that the SQL Server wasn't struggling. In my experience, "Select ISNULL(SomeColumn, '')..." is a better choice than adding "SomeColumn is not null" to a predicate. Finally, excluding null rows  might exhibit unexpected results in the app bc users might expect that to display but we just want to safely handle the error.

Answer (score 1):

Handling it from the DB side

1) Make sure Address is not NULL when inserting

```
INSERT INTO t(Address) VALUES(ISNULL(@Address, ''))
```

2) Return empty string instead if NULL

```
SELECT ISNULL(Address, '') as Address FROM t
```

And you already had good answers from other users `sqlReader.IsDBNull`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest/Best solution is to make your SQL query print other values instead of null. For example, If I have a column1 where I probably get null values, I would call this query :

```
SELECT isnull(column1,0) FROM table
```

which prints 0 instead of null values

Instead of calling this query :

```
SELECT column1 FROM table
```

which prints the null values and throws exceptions when retreiving data with C#.